# RealmTransactions IDE editor error: Expected Identifier

Tags: java, android, database, android-studio, realm

I am watching a realm tutorial and tried to implement the code inside `OnEditorActionListener`. That's the code. I am using Java 7 so there are no lambdas. The IDE says that the error is before new `Realm`. `Transaction.Callback`, where the `***` are, and the it expected identifier.

```
    myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
                if (myEditText.getText()!=null){
                    Realm.Transaction myTr = new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            Task newTask = realm.createObject(Task.class);
                            newTask.setText(myEditText.getText().toString());
                        }
                    }, *** new Realm.Transaction.Callback(){
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            Log.d("REALM TASK", "saved successfully");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(Exception ignore) {
                            Log.d("REALM TASK", "not saved");
                        }
                    };
                }
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            else {   return false;    }
        }
    });
```

I tried:

```
Realm.Transaction.Callback myCallback = (Realm.Transaction.Callback) myTr.Callback;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
                Realm.Transaction myTr = new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        Task newTask = realm.createObject(Task.class);
                        newTask.setText(myEditText.getText().toString());
                    }
                }, *** new Realm.Transaction.Callback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d("REALM TASK", "saved successfully");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception ignore) {
                        Log.d("REALM TASK", "not saved");
                    }
                };
```

should be

```
                final String text = myEditText.getText().toString();
                realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                        Task newTask = realm.createObject(Task.class);
                        newTask.setText(text);
                    }
                }, new Realm.Transaction.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d("REALM TASK", "saved successfully");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Exception e) {
                        Log.d("REALM TASK", "not saved", e);
                    }
                });
```